# How to get json value in key value pair?

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following being echoed from a custom wordpress post type by `get-client-logos.php`

```
[{
    "name": "One",
    "url": "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/random04-128x84.jpg"},
{
    "name": "Two",
    "url": "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/chuck_norris_random_fact_generator_6_3957_2224_image_2578-128x84.jpg"
}]​
```

I'm trying to extract the urls from each json object like so:

```
$.getJSON('get-client-logos.php/', function (data) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<img src ="' + val + '"/>');
  });

  console.log(items);
});
```

Upon console.logging, I get the following:

`["img src ="[object Object]"/", "img src ="[object Object]"/"]`

How does one return the value instead of the typeOf?

Comment: What is `value`?  You don't even have a variable with this name.  I assume this is a typo and your real code uses `val`?

Comment: Always makes me wonder how you can make a typo when pasting code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is an array of objects and so the `$.each` is going to pass the `index` and the `object`.. Try below code.

```
$.each(data, function(idx, val) {
 items.push('<img src ="' + val.url + '"/>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`val` is an object, you know that this object has a key called `url`. With dot notation you can get the value from the object.

```
$.getJSON('get-client-logos.php/', function (data) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<img src ="' + val.url + '"/>');
  });

  console.log(items);
});
```

The specific row is

```
items.push('<img src ="' + val.url + '"/>');
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON contains an array of objects, so in the `each`, the key is the array index and the value is the object. To get the value, use:

```
items.push('<img src ="' + val.url + '"/>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Try `val.url`

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<img src ="' + val.url + '"/>');
  });
```

Here in the first iteration val is an object

```
{"name": "One","url": "http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/random04-128x84.jpg"}
```

You need the `url` here..  So using `val.url` Or `val["url"]` should solve the problem..

Answer (score 1):

The array contains objects, you need to get the url property of the object

```
$.getJSON('get-client-logos.php/', function (data) {
  var items = [];

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<img src ="' + val.url + '"/>');
  });

  console.log(items);
});
```